# How to scan an integer 'n' and then declare an array[1000][n] in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

When I try scanning integer `n` and declaring an array, I am unable to get my correct output and when I debug it and print an element of the array, I get an error:
Cannot perform pointer math on incomplete types, try casting to a known type, or `void *`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n,i=0,j=0,k=0;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char string[10000];
    scanf("%s",string);
    char a[1000][n];

    while(isalnum(string[i])!=0)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            a[k][j]=string[i];
            i++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    i=0;
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        while(isalnum(a[i][j])!=0)
        {
            printf("%c",a[i][j]);
            i++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than `char a[1000][n];`, suggest `char *a = malloc(1000 * n * sizeof *a);` as `char a[1000][n];` likely is too large for your system.

Comment: On which line do you get the error ? And please foprmat your code

Comment: Your program works fine in my system without error.. Where do you get error can you mention..?

Comment: How big a value of `n` are you specifying?  If the value is in the thousands, you may be running out of stack space.  There's a limit, often 8 MiB on Unix systems, and rather smaller on Windows, I believe.  The limit can be adjusted, usually.

Comment: The value of n is small, I tested with n=5. I don't get an error when I compile and run it, I get a wrong answer. However, when I debug it with gdb.. once elements of string[] are supposed to get copied into a[][] i.e a[k][j]=string[i], I type p a[k][j] and I get that message.

Comment: @rohit235 What is your expected output ? You just have to store a alphanumeric char's from your input string to a char array and print it right?

Comment: for example, input is 5
toioynnkpheleaigshareconhtomesnlewx and output is theresnoplacelikehomeonasnowynightx

Comment: the program has to output column wise i.e a[0][0] then a[1][0] ... a[1][5].. a[2][0].. and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
while(isalnum(string[i])!=0)
    {
      for(j=0;j<n;j++)
      {
        a[k][j]=string[i];
        i++;
      }
      k++;
    }
```

There is a mistake in this loop, the `while` condition is checking for a `isalnum(string[i] != 0)` and inside the while loop you have a for loop where i is being incremented.
Just because you are not getting right output you seem to be assuming that array creation is causing the problem. But array creation is fine. It is your logic to achieve what you are trying to do is wrong.

If you just want to print the alphanumeric characters and ignore the rest of them it can done as shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int i=0,k=0;
   char s[10000];
   char a[10000];
   scanf("%s",s);

   while(s[i] != '\0')
   {   
      if(!isalnum(s[i]))
      {   
         i++;
         continue;
      }   
      else
         a[k++] = s[i];
      i++;
   }   
   a[k] = '\0';
   printf("%s\n",a);
   return 0;
}
```